# how to create automatic background image change in react native every time app opens up?

Tags: reactjs, image, background, styles, native

How can I make background image change everytime I open my app in react native ?

I am trying to make app with Native app for practice and decided to add some more dynamic style to it, but i cant figure out how to make it happen.

i keep getting syntax error or exports error when i try to add logic behind it

```
 import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  AsyncStorage,
  ImageBackground
} from "react-native";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";

import ToDo from "./ToDo";

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const noOfPic = 2;
const imgMap = {
  0: "img_0.jpg",
  1: "img_1.jpg",
  2: "img_2.jpg"
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    newToDo: "",
    loadedToDos: false,
    toDos: {}
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this._loadedToDos();
  };

  render() {
    const { newToDo, loadedToDos, toDos } = this.state;
    console.log(toDos);
    if (!loadedToDos) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
    
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/images/img_2.jpg')} style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <Text style={styles.title}>MS ToDo App</Text>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={"New To Do..."}
            value={newToDo}
            onChangeText={this._controlNewToDo}
            placeholderTextColor={"black"}
            returnKeyType={"done"}
            autoCorrect={false}
            onSubmitEditing={this._addToDo}
            underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
          />
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.toDos}>
            {Object.values(toDos)
              .sort((a, b) => {
                return a.createdAt - b.createdAt;
              })
              .map(toDo => (
                <ToDo
                  key={toDo.id}
                  deleteToDo={this._deleteToDo}
                  uncompleteToDo={this._uncompleteToDo}
                  completeToDo={this._completeToDo}
                  updateToDo={this._updateToDo}
                  {...toDo}
                />
              ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you want just random images every time the app is open right?

Comment: yes random images from my assets folder, everytime i open app again :)

Answer (score 0):

First let's map the images to an object

```
const imgMap = {
  0: "img_0.jpg",
  1: "img_1.jpg",
  2: "img_2.jpg",
  3: "img_3.jpg",
  4: "img_4.jpg"
};
```

Write a function that will return an image based on a random number. Each and every time you load the component/app, get a random number from 0-4 (Since you have 5 images)

**Putting up everything together**

```
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground } from "react-native";

const noOfPic = 4;
const imgMap = {
  0: "img_0.jpg",
  1: "img_1.jpg",
  2: "img_2.jpg",
  3: "img_3.jpg",
  4: "img_4.jpg"
};

const RandomPic = (props) => {
  function getRandomPic() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(noOfPic));
    return require(`./images/${imgMap[random]}`);
  }
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={getRandomPic()}
      style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }}
    />
  );
};

export default RandomPic;
```

Please make sure you check the working CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-random-image-background-md72s?file=/src/RandomPic.js:0-532

Comment: i know it should work  but i think im still messing it up :D

Comment: RandomPic.js: RandomPic.js:Invalid call at line 16: require("./images/" + imgMap[random])

Comment: what does that invalid call mean... i cant get it to work